# Prevent IIS7/ASP.NET locking directory with images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-locking

I have an ASP.NET webapp using the ASP.NET MVC 2 framework. It allows users to upload files to an uploads folder. The issue occurs when an image within a sub-folder is accessed by a web browser:

> http://mywebapp/uploads/image_gallery/sub_folder/image.jpg

The uploads folder is static and can't be modified by users, but anything below it is intended to be modifiable.

In the above example, the image_gallery folder becomes locked because w3wp.exe appears to create a handle on the sub_folder directory (using process explorer by sysinternals). I am still able to rename the sub_folder directory and the handle seems to stay with it after a rename, but i can't rename the parent folder (image_gallery in this case).

I can still browse within the folder and view other images and files etc. But can't rename the parent folder.

As this is using the MVC 2 framework i've put in an exclusion for the uploads folder like so:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("upload/{*pathInfo}");
```

into global.asax, so i'm assuming that ASP.NET is serving up those images directly (outside of the MVC framework)

So I guess my question is, is there any way to prevent IIS from putting a handle on specific directories or forcing it to remove a handle? Is the MVC 2 framework doing something tricky even though i have the ignoreroute specified?

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, directory handle gets created in worker processor because ASP.NET typically watches the file system for changes - this allows it to respond to change/addition of config files, new dlls etc.

I suggest that you move from the concept that users can control physical directory structure on the web server. Typically, what user can create is an logical directory structure but physical structure would be controlled by your program logic. Your logic will store the logical structure created by user and its mapping with actual physical structure on the web server.

Comment: Thanks @VinayC that confirms what I was thinking - that it was keeping track of the files for updates etc. I will proceed to wrap up the access to /uploads/ in a controller and go from there. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and after much investigating I've found the culprit:

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Setting this option (which makes all http modules run on ALL files, static ones included) to **false** fixed it for me.